# C# radiobutton keydown event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have made a simple code that will accept (enter key) the selected radiobutton. And check the radiobutton text if it matches with the answer. But this code is too redundant, is there a way to make it simpler?

```
private void btn1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
    var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
    if (btn1.Text == ans)
    {
    scoreAdd();
    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show(ans);
    }
    currentRow++;
    nextRow();
}

private void btn3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
    var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
    if (btn3.Text == ans)
    {
        scoreAdd();
        MessageBox.Show("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
            MessageBox.Show(ans);
    }
    currentRow++;
    nextRow();
}

private void btn4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
    var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
    if (btn4.Text == ans)
    {
        scoreAdd();
        MessageBox.Show("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
            MessageBox.Show(ans);
    }
    currentRow++;
    nextRow();
}
```

Comment: [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can cast `sender` to a `Button` (or whatever control type you're using) to get its text: `((Button)sender).Text` instead of `btn4.Text`.  At that point the rest of the code is the same, so a single handler can be used for all of the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a general method for the logic like:

```
protected void TheLogic(string txt)
{
   var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
    var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
    if (txt == ans)
    {
    scoreAdd();
    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show(ans);
    }
    currentRow++;
    nextRow();
}
```

Then call the `TheLogic` function in each `KeyDown` event using the corresponding parameter text, e.g.,

```
private void btn3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TheLogic(btn3.Text);
}

private void btn4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TheLogic(btn4.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;

  var row = dTable.Rows[currentRow];
  var ans = row["ANSWER"].ToString();
  if (button.Text == ans)
  {
      scoreAdd();
      MessageBox.Show("Correct");
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ans);
  }
  currentRow++;
  nextRow();
}
```

Just cast sender as Button and get Text from it.

And bind all event buttons to button_KeyDown.

This way you have only 1 method.